# Listening change event of taxonomy term checkboxes in Gutenberg editor

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I could do this well and easily in the classic editor but Gutenberg as I understand built and react and doesn't work on traditional vanilla js way.

## The Functionality I am trying to Achieve

1. User checks/unchecks a hierarchical taxonomy
2. Listen to changes and catch id of the term.
3. Change metabox UI using term id.

## What I've tried so far

I tried the traditional way of doing it. The following method doesn't work because I can't find any meaningful data attached to the change event.

```
     $("body").on(
        "change",
        ".editor-post-taxonomies__hierarchical-terms-list[aria-label=Channels]",
        function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    );
```

The direction towards a solution would help.

Comment: Listening to the checkboxes is a complete red herring and dead end for you. Think back to why you want to know if the checkbox was checked in the first place, you wanted to know if the post in the editor has a category or term, so you checked the checkbox. Instead, look at the main data store. The data store determines wether the checkbox is checked, not the other way around. In fact when the taxonomy panel is closed the checkbox element doesn't even exist!